# Simple C++ (or c) libraries for things such as fetching URL's

Tags: c++, iphone, c

I am needing to write some code that I can compile and run on Windows, OS/X, and iPhone. The iphone is fairly limited in what you can include. Are there any simple libraries or websites that provide source code for basic things that could be compiled and use on the iPhone as well as everything else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One of the popular libraries for HTTP access from C is [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/). A quick search showed that other people have been able to compile cURL at least as a static library for use in iPhone apps.

Answer (score 0):

If you find libCurl too heavy, [here is a list of alternatives](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/competitors.html). Some are specialized for HTTP, and might serve your need well.